# Hilos al buscar archivos recursivamente java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy intentando obtener los archivos y carpetas de forma recursiva en un ArrayList mediante hilos, ya que el programa si lo que busco tiene muchos archivos y directorios se queda congelado hasta que termina y no sé muy bien que tengo que hacer, este es el código sin hilos, funcionando, espero que alguien pueda explicarme como hacerlo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
                        if (lowercaseName.contains("prueba")) {
                                return true;
                        } else {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
    };

    ArrayList<File> archivos = new ArrayList(busqueda(new File(ruta),textFilter,true));
}

public static Collection busqueda(File directorio, FilenameFilter filtro, boolean recursivo) {

    Vector archivos = new Vector();

    File[] entries = directorio.listFiles();

    for (File entry : entries) {
        if (filtro == null || filtro.accept(directorio, entry.getName())) {
            archivos.add(entry);
        }

        if (recursivo && entry.isDirectory()) {
            archivos.addAll(busqueda(entry, filtro, recursivo));
        }
    }

    return archivos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes llamar al método `busqueda(...)` dentro de un hilo, como te muestro en el ejemplo:

```
    final ArrayList<File> archivos = new ArrayList<>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            archivos.addAll(busqueda(new File(ruta),textFilter,true));
        }
    }).start();
```

Es importante destacar que todas las variables que utilices dentro del hilo, si lo implementas de este modo, deben ser declaradas como `final`. Para evitar esto, puede utilizar algunas variantes de implementación como Crearte una clase que implemente la interfaz `Runnable` y pasarle los parámetros del método al constructor de dicha clase. Algo así:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<File> target;
    private File ruta;
    private FilenameFilter filter;
    private boolean recursivo;

    public MyRunnable(List<File> target, File ruta, FilenameFilter filter, boolean recursivo) {
        super();
        this.target = target;
        this.ruta = ruta;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.recursivo = recursivo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        target.addAll(busqueda(ruta, filter, true));
    }
}
```

luego lo utilizas así: `new Thread(new MyRunnable(archivos, new File(ruta), textFilter, true)).start();`

Por supuesto, el método `busqueda(...)` debe ser accesible por la clase `MyRunnable`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy muy verde aún, gracias de nuevo!!